# Prove that an invertible linear-map like $\phi : V \to V$ exists such that $\phi(v_i)=w_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Assume that $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ and $\{w_1,\dots,w_k\}$ are two linearly-independent subsets of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$.
Prove that there exists an invertible linear-map $\phi : V \to V$ such that $\forall i \in \{1,2,\dots,k\}\space\space\phi(v_i)=w_i$

Note 1 : Notice that there are two or three similar questions but none of them is exactly my question. So, This is not a duplicate.

Note 2 : I've learned three theorems which i think are useful here.
Theorem 1 : If $T : V \to W$ is a linear map then these 3 statements are equivalent :
(i) $T$ is one-to-one.
(ii) $Ker(T)=\{0_v\}$
(iii) $T$ takes each linearly-independent subset of $V$ , to a linearly-independent subset of $W$.

Theorem 2 : Assume that $V$ and $W$ are two vector spaces and $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$ and $w_1,\dots,w_n$ are some members of $W$ which are chosen arbitrarily.  There exists a unique linearly-map $T : V\to W$ such that $T(v_i)=w_i$

Theorem 3 : If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $T : V \to V $ is a linear-map, then $T$ is one-to-one iff $T$ is surjective.

So I have accepted these theorems and there is no need to prove them again.

Note 3 : My problem is that i don't know how to make a relation between these theorems and the question accurately. They seem to be related. I'm confused ...  I also don't know how to define that $\phi$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is not it a standard result...? Grabbing almost any linear algebra textbook, you will see :). A side remark regarding math writing. The statement "there is some real number $x$ such that $x^{2} = 2$" means in plain language "there is some real number such that its square is equal to 2". It does not make sense to let the word "like" play :).

Comment: @WalkingBlues So, what's wrong with the word "like" ? :D

Comment: Logically the word is improper! You know, "there is no one like her" presupposes things about this "she". You can then reason out :). Besides, the example in the previous comment of mine shows that "like" is redundant...

Comment: @WalkingBlues ok :D you convinced me :) i'm gonna edit ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a finite-dimensional space, any linearly independent set can be extended to a basis.  So extend your two given sets to form bases
$$\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}\quad\hbox{and}\quad \{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}\ ,$$
where $n$ is the dimension of $V$.  For any $x$ in $V$ we can write
$$x=\alpha_1v_1+\cdots+\alpha_nv_n$$
and define
$$\phi(x)=\alpha_1w_1+\cdots+\alpha_nw_n\ .$$
You need to check that

- $\phi$ is well defined (hint: $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis);
- $\phi$ is linear (basic algebra);
- $\phi(v_i)=w_i$ (easy);
- $\phi$ is invertible (hint: $\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ is a basis; theorem 1(i),(ii); theorem 3).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I understand everything but $\phi(v_i)=w_i$ ( which in your idea, is easy !!! ) Why is this true ?

Comment: For example, if $x=v_1$ then $\alpha_1=1$ and all other $\alpha$s are $0$, so $\phi(x)=\cdots\,$?

Comment: Oh ... my bad !!! Excuse me :)))